# How to specify the child element in a WebDriverWait expected condition?

Tags: python, selenium

Lets say you have an element on a webpage found successfully

```
parent_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(some_css_selector)
```

I want to enact a WebDriverWait which waits until one of its child elements is clickable.  Usually you would do that with

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,some_css_selector)))
```

however in my case I want some_css_selector to be the child element of parent_element. How can I do this?

Edit: For instance - I have learned that I can do this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
child_element = wait.until(lambda d:parent_element.find_element_by_css_selector('child_selector'))
```

which seems to work. However this is just waiting until that child element appears. I want to use the expected conditions (such as element_to_be_clickable).

Comment: would be usseful if you provide your url

Comment: I can't provide a url as its a password protected site

Comment: from your question its unclear which element you are trying to access with parent child relationship

Comment: that's true, maybe I can edit my question to make it non-specific to my use case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are trying to pass by locator CSS_SELECTOR, so you have to locate using parent-child relationship:

```
  WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR,//Parent-selector > child-Selector))
```

I am able to pass the webelement in java with element_to_be_clickable, i am not sure whether it will work in python or not. You can give it a try.

```
child_element= parent_element.find_element_by_css_selector('child_selector')
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(child-element))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle child element based on presence of parent then you can use sibling function to fetch sibling to the parent web element, in simple words. [How to deal with sibling using selenium](https://www.softwaretestingclass.com/using-contains-sibling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium/)

Also there another way you can use if loop and check for child based on presence of your parent element.

```
if parent:
    if child:
        print "do stuff"
    else:
        print "failed to locate child"
else:
     print "failed to locate parent"
```

Comment: I don't quite understand... I know that the parent exists. And I know that the child exists. My question is specifically about using the Expected Conditions for a child selector in a wait. I don't see how that would integrate here.

Comment: ok, if you go to google.com and check this //div[@class='szppmdbYutt__middle-slot-promo']//child::a xpath you will get to know is your parent element and in the parent your are trying to locate anchor tag .